# Using Gravity Forms to upload media into library, then attach to post

Tags: wordpress, upload, frontend, gravity-forms-plugin, media-library

I have a simple site with two Gravity Forms, both of which allow users to upload media.

I'm looking for some simple code that:

(a) inserts all uploaded media into the Media Library and not the default Gravity Forms folder
(b) attaches media to pages. Form 1 attach to page 1, form 2 to page 2.

I've found a few similar posts, but nothing simple that does exactly what I need.

I guess I'd use something like

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_1', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );
```

and

```
wp_insert_attachment
```

Because I only have two forms, would something simple in the functions.php that adds media to the library then depending on which form was used attaches to posts work?

Reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment gives me some idea, but I can't get it to take the media from the submitted form and add it to the media library. It attaches to the post, sorta, but obviously isnt the correct media as it isnt attaching.

Answer (score 0):

My plugin, Gravity Forms Media Library, provides this functionality for Gravity Forms: https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-media-library/

Comment: Sidenote.... that is a premium plugin, i.e. it is not free. Amazing features though.